# Error with installing docker-compose (def _collate(*iterables, key=lambda a: a, reverse=False)

Tags: python, python-2.7, docker, docker-compose

Observing following error while checking/executed `docker-compose -v` cmd after installing it with apt-get install docker-compose. 
Please suggest how to resolve this issue ?

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/docker-compose", line 7, in <module>
    from compose.cli.main import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 23, in <module>
    from ..bundle import get_image_digests
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/bundle.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .config.serialize import denormalize_config
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/config/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .config import ConfigurationError
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/config/config.py", line 50, in <module>
    from .validation import match_named_volumes
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/config/validation.py", line 12, in <module>
    from jsonschema import Draft4Validator
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jsonschema/__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    import importlib_metadata as metadata
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/importlib_metadata/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    import zipp
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zipp.py", line 12, in <module>
    import more_itertools
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/more_itertools/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from more_itertools.more import *  # noqa
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/more_itertools/more.py", line 340
    def _collate(*iterables, key=lambda a: a, reverse=False):

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Following is the Ansible code to install docker compose, along with python, pip, docker repo :

```
   - name: Install Python 2.7.12
      raw: test -e /usr/bin/python || (apt -y update && apt install -y python-minimal)

    - name: Install pip
      apt:
          name: python-pip
          update_cache: yes
          state: latest
      become: true
      become_method: sudo

    <code to add docker repo  , docker package >   

    - name: Install Docker-py (pegged to version 1.9 to work around bug referenced at https://github.com/StanfordBioinformatics/loom/issues/205)
      pip: name=docker

    - name: Download and install docker-compose to /usr/local/bin
      pip: name=docker-compose
```

Comment: This does not appear to be the entire error thrown. Could you please share the last line that appears in the `Traceback`?

Comment: ```SyntaxError: invalid syntax``` is the last line. have also updated this in the error

Answer (score 3):

This error...

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/more_itertools/more.py", line 340
    def _collate(*iterables, key=lambda a: a, reverse=False):

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

...indicates that the code is using syntax appropriate for Python 3, but you're using Python 2. This may be a packaging bug, but you haven't provided enough information in your question to figure that out. If you want to update your question to indicate what distribution and version you're running, we can look into resolutions.

The error is coming from the `more-itertools` package. You can work around this particular problem by running:

```
pip install more-itertools==5.0.0
```

This will install a version of `more-itertools` that is compatible with Python 2.

Comment: Yes, we are using python2 in ansible script.

Comment: Have updated the question with ansible script snippet

Comment: Thanks Iarsks, this helped. Can you suggest how can i incorporate this in ansible script ?

Comment: You can just add another `pip` task like the ones you already have, but for `name` specify `more-itertools==5.0.0`.

Comment: ```- name: Downgrade more-itertools to 5.0.0 (Python 2.7 supported)
      pip:
        name: more-itertools==5.0.0```